# What does `delete <table name>` in PLSQL code mean?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, temp-tables

I have a PLSQL code with the following line of code.

```
delete my_table;
```

Where `my_table` is a Global Temporary Table. I am guessing the above code means, delete all rows from the table. However, I am unable to google out any result.

Comment: deleting all rows from the table. if this is global temporary check the definition because it might also gets truncated on commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FROM` keyword and `WHERE` clause [are optional](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8005.htm).